# looking a way to combine these methods in generic way on same return type

Tags: c#, .net, list, generics, entity-framework-core

I have got below three methods and they are returning same return type and the only difference among these three methods is that the data is getting retrieved from different tables.

Below are those methods.

```
public IQueryable<SpaceFunctionType> GetSpaceFunctionForA170(string airFlowSource)
{
    return _dbContext.A170.Where(s => s.AirflowSourceName == airFlowSource)
                          .Select(c => new SpaceFunctionType
                          {
                              Category = c.Category,
                              SpaceFunction = c.SpaceFunction
                          });
}

public IQueryable<SpaceFunctionType> GetSpaceFunctionForA621(string airFlowSource)
{
    return _dbContext.A621.Where(s => s.AirflowSourceName == airFlowSource)
                          .Select(c => new SpaceFunctionType
                          {
                              Category = c.Category,
                              SpaceFunction = c.SpaceFunction
                          });
}

public IQueryable<SpaceFunctionType> GetSpaceFunctionForEquipment(string airFlowSource)
{
    return _dbContext.Equipments.Where(s => s.EquipmentSourceName == airFlowSource)
                          .Select(c => new SpaceFunctionType
                          {
                              Category = c.Category,
                              SpaceFunction = c.SpaceFunction
                          });
}
```

Could any one please help me suggest any ideas on this how to combine these methods in a generic way. I am using Entity Framework Core.

Comment: Honestly I would not combine these. They do different things. Why do you think it is necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF DbContext has a `.Set<TDomain>()` method that returns the set of objects based on the type. You can literally write-

```
public IQueryable<SpaceFunctionType> Get<TDomain>(string airFlowSource) where TDomain: IA
{
    return _dbContext.Set<TDomain>().Where(s => s.EquipmentSourceName == airFlowSource)
                          .Select(c => new SpaceFunctionType
                          {
                              Category = c.Category,
                              SpaceFunction = c.SpaceFunction
                          });
}
```

Now to add common functionality, add an interface -

```
public interface IA {
    ... AirflowSourceName 
}
```

Derive from interface -

```
public class A170: IA
{}

public class A621 : IA 
{}

public class Equipments: IA
{}
```

more details https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext.set?view=entity-framework-6.2.0

**UPDATE** Since they are different properties. You can inject a expression lambda to compare for you.-

```
public IQueryable<SpaceFunctionType> Get<TDomain>(Expression<Func<TDomain, bool>> predicate) where TDomain: IA
{
    return _dbContext.Set<TDomain>().Where(predicate)
                          .Select(c => new SpaceFunctionType
                          {
                              Category = c.Category,
                              SpaceFunction = c.SpaceFunction
                      });
}
```

and call like this -

```
.Get<A70>(x => x.AirflowSourceName == "forcename");
```

or

```
.Get<Equipments>(x => x.EquipmentSourceName == "forcename");
```

**UPDATE 2**

The interface need to be updated as -

```
public interface IA {
    ... Category
    ... SpaceFunction
}
```

Without this, the `Select` clause will not know that there are properties with such names, but since these are common to all, adding them to interface should not be a problem..

Comment: True, but they also query different properties, i.e. `s.AirflowSourceName`

Comment: You could Also add property as a lambda. I will update with it.

Comment: I believe you mean "literally write" ;)

Comment: @brainlesscoder thanks for the suggestion and one more query is what are the properties that i need to mention in that `interface(IA)`

Comment: not every properties, only the one that you need inside the method. The interface there is just for example. if you are going to use the generic approach (the 2nd one), you will need `Category` and `SpaceFunction` to be part of the interface. I will update the answer for better understanding......... updated.

Comment: @brainlesscoder i am getting error at this `Set<TDomain>().Where(predicate)` and the error is `The type 'TDomain' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method` could you please let me know what will be the modification for the above code

Comment: try using `where TDomain: IA, class` instead of `where TDomain: IA`

Comment: nope it is not working either way , if you can please look at this that would be very grateful to me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59868996/getting-an-error-on-trying-to-call-method-in-generic-way?noredirect=1#comment105869730_59868996 thanks

Comment: @brainlesscoder how to call that function i am calling like as you mentioned in the answer but getting an error like as mentioned in that post

Comment: The call is okay, but the definition of classes is not. Check my answer again, notice the relation between `TDomain`, `IA` and class `Equipments` and then compare with yours. You will notice that , `IA` is common between `TDomain` and `Equipments` but in your implementation, it is not.