# getting an error on trying to call method in generic way

Tags: c#, .net, list, entity-framework, generics

Hi all I am trying to filter the table using where class by passing parameter to the method like as below,

```
    private IQueryable<SpaceFunctionType> Get<TEntity>(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate) where TEntity : class, ICategorySpaceFunction
    {
        return _dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Where(predicate)
                              .Select(c => new SpaceFunctionType
                              {
                                  Category = c.Category,
                                  SpaceFunction = c.SpaceFunction
                              });
    }

   public IQueryable<SpaceFunctionType> GetSpaceFunctionType(string environmentSource)
   {
        return Get<LibraryEnvironment>(x => x.EnvironmentSource.Name == environmentSource).AsQueryable();
   }
```

and these are the interface details,

```
public interface ICategorySpaceFunction
{
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string SpaceFunction { get; set; }
}
```

and this will be the class name

```
public class SpaceFunctionType : ICategorySpaceFunction
{
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string SpaceFunction { get; set; }
}
```

but getting an error here `Get<LibraryEnvironment>` like as below

> The type 'API.DesignHub.Entities.LibraryEnvironment' cannot be used
>   as type parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method
>   'Query.Get(Expression>)'. There is no
>   implicit reference conversion from
>   'API.DesignHub.Entities.LibraryEnvironment' to
>   'API.DesignHub.Entities.ICategorySpaceFunction'

I am not sure where i am doing wrong with the above method, Could any one please suggest any idea on this that would be very grateful to me,

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Need [MCVE], but it looks like `LibraryEnvironment` is not `ICategorySpaceFunction` as error says...

Comment: yes both are different i just updated my question

Comment: The error is what it  is happening. But the language used there is a bit generic. What it means is `LibraryEnvironment` does not implement `ICategorySpaceFunction`. `TEntity` is a type of `ICategorySpaceFunction` and you are sending `LibraryEnvironment` when calling, so it is a rule that `LibraryEnvironment` should be similar to `TEntity`, which is an implementation of `ICategorySpaceFunction`. more details - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is what it  is happening. But the language used there is a bit generic. What it means is `LibraryEnvironment` does not implement `ICategorySpaceFunction`. `TEntity` is a type of `ICategorySpaceFunction` and you are sending `LibraryEnvironment` when calling, so it is a rule that `LibraryEnvironment` should be similar to `TEntity`, which is an implementation of `ICategorySpaceFunction`. more details - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters